# My Save Config Button [Stores>Configuration] in Magento 2.3.3 Doesn't Work

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

I can't make any changes because after making the changes the save config button just doesn't work.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Hello
Does any error log add in  system.log?

Comment: can you please check in console as in magento default 2.3.3 save config button is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Open all the fieldsets in the catalog tab. Most probably there is a field in one of them that is not valid and there is a js error message that prevents the form from submitting.
If you open all of them you should see the one with problems.

If you got it this type error in inspect.

[image]

You need to deploy the area of backend.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area adminthml
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work out. Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: Hello,
Which configuration did is't save working?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:-** First Require remove the `var/page_cache , var/session andvar/view_preprocessed` after run the :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Case 2:-** There is two possible problem

1) page coming from cache ( first check is that configuration save into `core_config_data`)

2) php post size issue

add below thing into a `.htaccess` file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value max_input_nesting_level 128
php_value max_input_vars 7000
```

any query let me know.